# File not showing in Git status when it is meant to be

Tags: linux, git, zsh

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
# Ignore everything by default.
*

# Zsh
!.zshrc

# Git
!.gitconfig
!.gitignore

# Lock.sh
!.config/lock.sh

# Xresources
!.Xresources
```

but still when I do `git add .config/lock.sh`:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.config/lock.sh
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

and it does not show up in `git status`?

Answer (score 1):

[Git-SCM](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

That's is probably the reason. In addition you are presented an option to include it. It seems odd to exclude every file.